# Evaluate the definite integral $\int_4^8 e^{4-x}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, solution-verification

5.4

Evaluate the definite integral $\int_4^8 e^{4-x}dx$

Can somebody verify this solution for me?? Thanks!

---

So we could evalute this with $u$ substitution, by letting $u=4-x$ and proceeding like that... But instead I'm going to do something else:

$\int_4^8 e^{4-x}dx$

$=\int_4^8 e^{4}e^{-x}dx$

$= e^{4}\int_4^8e^{-x}dx$

$= e^{4}(\frac{e^{-x}}{-1}|_4^8)$

$= -e^{4}(e^{-x}|_4^8)$

$= -e^{4}(e^{-8}-e^{-4})$

$= (-e^{4})e^{-8}-(-e^{4})e^{-4})$

$= -e^{-4}+1$

Comment: A minus at the beginning ....

Comment: You lost a minus when you multiplied by $-e^4$.

Comment: I dont know if its correct to say, but you dont have to post every question of exercise that you solve! For same type of problems you can trust your intuition that it should be correct, only if you feel that there is serious need to verify, i think then you should post. Otherwise there will be a flood of exercise questions and not conceptual or theoretical ones! But as you consider! It will be a waste of time on your part too if you type all exercise questions!

Comment: It's for my students... Corona shutdown >.<. This is a good place to post worked solutions, for both formatting purposes and to get insight from other math nerds.

Comment: @MSV But posting 4 similar questions within an hour? You could rather use an integral calculator to verify your answer.

Comment: It's for my students during the corona virus shutdown, working out solutions that they have had problems on

Comment: @MSV  If you are *teaching* your students, you should be able to calculate such integrals without need of consulting math.se for every one of them.  What did you do when teaching in the classroom?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be $(-e^4)e^{-8}-(-e^4)e^{-4}=\color{red}-e^{-4}+1$.

Comment: this answer was entered before the question was edited

Comment: Still, J.W., your *answer* should have been a comment, because it does not answer the question, but rather comments on a problem in the question. "Use comments to ask for more information or suggest improvements."  Every comment field we all see regularly, until we type in a comment.

Comment: The question asked for solution verification.  My answer was that the solution provided in the question was correct except for a missing minus sign.  Perhaps I should have been more explicit